# If the Quran is a perfect book, why are there so many interpretations?

Tags: tafseer

If the Quran is a perfect book, why are there so many interpretations?

If a book is "perfect", as many Muslims claim the Quran to be, shouldn't an integral part of that perfection be a self-explanatory and clear, unambiguous nature that does not necessitate interpretations by scholars and experts, who, as humans, can only inject their own subjectivities in them?

Comment: Why would you think that would be a criteria of "perfection"?  Aren't many of the greatest works of literature those that actually make you *think* rather than those that just straight out tell you things?

Comment: ^ I would say that the Quran can still make you think, and yet be clear and free of ambiguity and greatly differing interpretations. I don't believe the two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 answers.

1. Start learn Arabic language and you will see that a lot of words have more than 10 meanings. This happens because of the fact that practically all words in Arabic has 3-literal root. Simple math gives you that there are only  21 952 combinations. Okay, even 100 000 is really small amount of words. So a lot of words have many different meanings.
2. Assume that you are reading some book like "What is good and what is bad". You can read it twice and it will be enough to extract possible information. It is not about Quran, you can think about some verses many years and you will not be able to extract all meanings.

> 38:29. [This is] a blessed Book which We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], that they might reflect upon its verses and that those of understanding would be reminded.